# How can I filter incoming email and then forward to another MX server?

Tags: email, mx-record

Currently, I have an organisation set up in Gmail with a custom domain. I’d like to pre-filter all emails being received at that domain - think a transparent email proxy if you will.

My DNS MX is currently set to Google’s servers. I’d like to change them to a server I have control of to pre-filter the emails.

Preferably I’d like a lightweight docker solution to this problem.

Is this possible, and if so how do I go about this?

The searches I’ve done so far mention sending emails to another domain, or SMTP relaying - both of which aren’t what I want.

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit more, what kind of filtering do want to do, spam filtering?

Comment: Actually relaying is more or less exactly what you'll be doing. You point your MX record(s) to the servers that will be doing the filtering. Those servers will accept mail addressed to your domain (and maybe do some more validation before accepting those messages) ; do whatever filtering you want and then make a routing decision; accept and forward the message over SMTP to the servers hosting your users mailboxes (that is relaying), or quarantine, reject or even silently discard the message. Make sure that your own IP is trusted or at least won't ever be blacklisted by the destination.

Comment: Check out this one https://docker-mailserver.github.io/docker-mailserver/latest/

Comment: You can't relay back to Google as they require to be in the MX record. But you can surely relay somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure the MX to go another service, that would relay to your organization after, but most of these solution are antispam solution.

It really depend on your need.

You could configure a spamassasin that pre-filter, you could go too on a cloud based services like TrendMicro Email security, or use any other service like that. Most of those service allow to see all log, and check for error.

I often do that even for O365 customer, as by default the protection feature was weak in the past. (It allowed like a tenant to spoof an email from another tenant, as the SPF check was ok (as all tenant got the same SPF), but they fixed that issue last November, which is good)

I never seen the use of a transparent proxy for mail use, as the email already support to be relayed unlike a http/https request. In the end to be able to configure an transparent proxy you would need to control the network where the mail server is, and in your case you don't.